# Unknown player for Shadowbox URL - jQuery

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I am using the shadowbox.js for display the images of a gallery with this effect. Everything works fine. My problem is when I have an image with a link as a name, for example:
http://www.fakedomainname.org/myimage1

I got an error: unknown player iframe

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: My problem also is that this image has not ending like .png for example. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadowbox does not recognize the content if there is no .jpg / .png / .gif extension.
This works however:

```
Shadowbox.open({
    content:    'http://www.abc.com/myimage1',
    player:     "img" 
});
```

or define the player in the link:

```
<a href='http://www.abc.com/myimage1' rel='shadowbox;player=img'>test</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I found the problem. I just need to include the shadowbox.js with External sites and pages also. I had the simple one. So it just worked fine.

Comment: If the external link is an image you only need the "img" player. You can use the "iframe" player for external images but then the auto-scaling functions of Shadowbox are not used. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/EDqet/1/

Comment: Not related to this question, but great help for me getting "img" not "image".